# Is there any way to off() all listeners when a user is de-authorized

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In Firebase the documentation states that you must call `off()` on all parent and children nodes, as-well as if the listener was added more than once you must call `off()` the amount of times the listener was added to turn them all off.

In my application the user accumulates heaps of child listeners through user interaction and using Firebase for states. The average user will have 100+ listeners at any given time.

Is there a simple way that I'm missing to just turn off ALL listeners when `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(...)` is called and the user was deauthorized?

Comment: Can't you just call theNode.removeAllObservers? Also I think you may mean unauthenticated instead of deauthorized.

Comment: `removeAllObservers` will only remove the observers from that specific node. It does not work recursively.

Comment: All listeners to nodes that require authentication will automatically be cancelled when the user becomes unauthenticated. You can easily check that by listening for errors, those will fire in that scenario.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That should be an answer.

Comment: :-) If it is indeed what Hobbyist is asking about, it could be. But it would also be a (hard to search for) duplicate in that case, because I'm pretty sure I said the same not too long ago.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So these listeners will be canceled based on $validate rules, is that correct? Considering I have not set up security rules yet, is it safe to say that the observers will not be removed?